# Why am I getting a cmake error while installing latte-dock from git?

Tags: kubuntu, wayland, cmake, latte-dock

I am using kubuntu(wayland).
I started following the installation documentation on github to install latte-dock:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade

sudo apt install cmake extra-cmake-modules qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev libkf5iconthemes-dev libkf5plasma-dev libkf5windowsystem-dev libkf5declarative-dev libkf5xmlgui-dev libkf5activities-dev build-essential libxcb-util-dev libkf5wayland-dev git gettext libkf5archive-dev libkf5notifications-dev libxcb-util0-dev libsm-dev libkf5crash-dev libkf5newstuff-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libx11-dev libx11-xcb-dev kirigami2-dev libwayland-dev libwayland-client0 plasma-wayland-protocols libqt5waylandclient5-dev qtwayland5-dev-tools

sh install.sh
```

its the third(installation) step that I am getting a cmake error at:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:39 (find_package):
By not providing "FindLibTaskManager.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"LibTaskManager", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LibTaskManager"
with any of the following names:

LibTaskManagerConfig.cmake
libtaskmanager-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "LibTaskManager" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"LibTaskManager_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"LibTaskManager" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
has been installed.
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to install from here? https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+index?batch=75&direction=backwards&memo=375&start=300 latte-dock is not apparently an included package. Or, are you trying to install from here? https://github.com/KDE/latte-dock/blob/master/INSTALLATION.md If that is the case, you missed a step. Before sh install.sh, please try: `cd latte-dock` Please clarify your intention. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Well I'm just following the steps on the installation.md file on the latte-dock github page which asked me to add the backports repository in order to install dependency.
And I did use `cd latte-dock` but its still giving me the cmake error

Comment: By the way, Latte Dock has been abandoned by its main developer and has been in maintenance mode. It is very unlikely that the existing bugs will be fixed. It may gradually become incompatible with future KDE Plasma versions

Comment: Yes I just learnt about that. I don't know whether I should be asking questions like this on ask Ubuntu but is there a good substitute for latte dock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install plasma-workspace-dev
cd ~/latte-dock  #Or wherever you cloned the source code from git
sudo rm -r build
sudo sh install.sh
```

It builds, albeit with a few possibly harmless warnings, on my 23.10 system.